# keyguardmanager createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent is showing on device lock screen

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-security, keyguard

I'm using android native keyguardmanager class. I'm calling createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent() in onresume everytime.

Open Activity > Lock the device > Unlock the device > lock it quickly. keyguardmanager window is showing on device lock screen. How to dismiss the window & I don't want to show it on device lock screen. It should do everything under device lock screen.
 My Code:

```
 keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            Intent screenLockIntent = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                screenLockIntent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("My App", "");
            }
            this.startActivityForResult(screenLockIntent,LOCK_REQUEST_CODE);
```